# Testing student scripts in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, automated-tests

I am a teacher in a secondary school and have been using Python to solve simple tasks for several years. I am interesting in writing automated tests to run on students code to automate the marking process.

I've also been interested in TFD so unit testing seems a natural avenue to explore. I have written a test where I ask students to modify several functions and procedures within a script. I can then manually run a test script against each submission to give them a score by importing there file.

Know the crunch...
I'm struggling to write a script that will iterate through a sub-folder system to run my test script against all submissions. As you can imagine this would be a significant help in reducing marking time.

The folder structure is generated by the way they submit their work electronically. I end up with an assignment folder and then a sub-folder inside this with the students work.
e.g. "Assignment 1 Folder" and then inside that a folder for each student who submitted e.g. "Anthony Student Folder", "Another Student Folder" etc (About 23 students).

Each student will edit a script that asks them to write a function or a procedure. Here is an example:

```
# =======================================================================
# Test 1  
# Write a function called 'MyCubed' that takes an integer number as an
# argument and returns the cube of that number.  E.g. calling it with 2
# should give 8.
# =======================================================================
# Code HERE the following code is a student response.  
def MyCubed(num):  
    return num**3
```

So I've created a testing file that I can put in each students folder and run to test each file.

```
# =======================================================================
# Test 1  
# Cube an integer  
test1 = 0  
ModuleExist = True  
try:  
    test1 = Python_Test.MyCubed(3) 
except:  
    print('\nTest 1: Failed: MyCubed not present')  
    ModuleExist = False  
if ModuleExist:  
    if test1 == 27:  
        print('\nTest 1: My Cubed Passed')
        score += 10
    elif test1 != 0:
        print('\nTest 1: Failed expected 27, actually-', test1)
```

This script contains 8 tests (modules) to tested/run on the scripts. 
So I was hoping to iterate through the list of student folders and import that students solution and run with test case.

I can put the file in each folder and run them individually but I'd like to automate it to iterate through all the sub-folders.

Comment: Your question is clear, but what you have did so far? Which kind of problems you faced in your codes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what this code will do, It's going to save all the list of files in a folder in a list and for each and every file in that folder you can run your script with their file name as arguments. If this seems like a solution to your problem, you can use the following code.

```
import os
from subprocess import Popen
content_list = []
for content in os.listdir(<Path>): # Path to the directory where student Scripts were there
    content_list.append(content)
for item in content_list:
    pobj = Popen([executable, '<Your_script>'+item], bufsize=-1, stdout=sout, stderr=serr)
    pobj.wait()
```